# Method not found when trying to open builds from TFS in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, build

I am getting a Method not found exception when trying to access TFS builds in Visual Studio 2015. I tried adding the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll version 14.0.24712.0 to GAC and the issue still persists.

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod, System.Guid, System.Object, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.ApiResourceVersion, System.Net.Http.HttpContent, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1>, System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.

[image]

Comment: Did this error only occurs on your machine ?How about other colleagues?  Besides, did it ever works well with VS2015?

Comment: 1. With the same user is it working on a different machine?
2. If you have admin rights on the machine did you try opening VS as admin?
3. For other users is it working on the machine where issue is there?
4. If it works for other users perhaps it is an issue with your user profile. So you could clear your profile and create a new one?
5. Did you try a different version of supported visual studio?
6. Did you repair the Visual Studio installation?

Comment: Clearing the cache was the last thing I wanted to do. Wanted to check if there is any less drastic solution out there and if somebody else faced this issue. I did go ahead and cleared the cache. I don't see that error anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works well on other colleagues's machine with VS2015, this seems to be a client issue.

You could first try to [clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). If it still not work, reinstall the VS2015 may do the trick(*not recommend*).

Comment: Clearing the cache was one of my options but wanted to check if there is any less drastic solution out there and if somebody else faced this issue. I did go ahead and cleared the cache. I don't see that error anymore. Thank you.